# Next.js 14 "Intercepting routes" feature not working in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

**TLDR**

"Intercepting routes" feature works locally (localhost:3000)

"Intercepting routes" feature does not work in production (website.com)

---

**Here is video showing problem**

https://streamable.com/ji9cvs

---

**The problem**

I am trying to make a feature where

when you click on a specific element, a black box appears.

To make this feature, I am using the "intercepting routes" feature.

It works fine locally, but does not work in production.

Locally, on localhost:3000, when I click on the text, "Image 1", a black box appears (expected)

However, in production at https://resplendent-halva-bdccd9.netlify.app/

when I click on the text, "Image 1", I am taken to another page (unexpected)

A black box should be appearing.

---

**My project structure looks like this**

- /app

  - @modal

    - default.tsx
    - (.)photos

      - [id]

        - page.tsx
  - default.tsx
  - layout.tsx
  - page.tsx
  - photos

    - [id]

      - page.tsx

---

app/layout.tsx

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
  metadataBase: new URL('https://nextgram.vercel.app'),
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  modal,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  modal: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {children}
        {modal}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

app/default.tsx

```
export default function Default() {
    return null;
}
```

app/page.tsx

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link href="/photos/1">Image 1</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

app/photos/[id]/page.tsx

```
export default function PhotoPage({
    params: { id },
  }: {
    params: { id: string };
  }) {
    return <div className="card">{id}</div>;
  }
```

app/@modal/(.photos)/[id]/page.tsx

```
   export default function PhotoModal({
        params: { id: photoId },
    }: {
        params: { id: string }
    }) {
        return <div className="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full bg-black">MODAL SHOWING</div>
    }
```

**Similar app**

My code is similar to vercel's nextgram app found at https://github.com/vercel/nextgram

**Here is my code**

https://github.com/478732/temp